# Setting heap size for CorbTask

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9, ml-gradle, marklogic-corb

In my build.gradle, I have a task of type CorbTask, where I am looking to execute some process over a large number of URIs. In this case, I am processing a little less than 800,000 URIs.

```
task updateSharePointMetadata(type: com.marklogic.gradle.task.CorbTask) {
  classpath = configurations.corb
  xccUrl = "xcc://${mlUsername}:${mlPassword}@${mlHost}:${mlStagingPort}"
  urisModule = "corb/selectSharepointMetadata.xqy|ADHOC"
  processModule = "corb/updateBinarySizeInSharePointMetadata.xqy|ADHOC"
  threadCount = 8
  batchSize = 100
  batchUriDelim=','
}
```

When I run this task... during the process of queuing up the URIs, I get a OutOfMemoryError, Out of Heap space. When the task is run... or at least I did earlier, now at least it runs.. but I still see the Free Memory warning as it queues up the uris.

```
WARNING: free memory: 35 MiB of 394
```

In the gradle properties I already have the `org.gradle.jvmargs` parameter setup to pass in the `-Xmx` setting, but it does not seem to make any difference. I assume this is because the CorbTask extends JavaExec, which is spawned off. So I looked at maybe setting the `jvmArgs` property on the CorbTask, but that is not settable.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried this yet? tasks.withType(JavaExec) {
  jvmArgs = ['-Xms1g', '-Xmx2g']
}

Comment: This worked. Thanks @grtjn

Comment: @grtjn where can i add this "tasks.withType(JavaExec) { jvmArgs = ['-Xms1g', '-Xmx2g'] } " line

Comment: In build.gradle works just fine. Near the top, but below 'plugins' and 'buildscript'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **[DISK-QUEUE](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2#DISK-QUEUE)** option was added for scenarios such as this.

Rather than trying to bump up your memory settings and hope that a large set of URIs will fit, you can enable the **[DISK-QUEUE](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2#DISK-QUEUE)** option.

- You can configure **[DISK-QUEUE-MAX-IN-MEMORY-SIZE](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2#DISK-QUEUE-MAX-IN-MEMORY-SIZE)**, which will set a limit for how many URIs are queued in memory. The rest will spill to disk in temp files.
- You can set where the files are generated with the **[DISK-QUEUE-TEMP-DIR](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2#DISK-QUEUE-TEMP-DIR)** (default location is the java.io.tmpdir)

Comment: As a follow up to this. I have the another case, where I have the DISK QUEUE enabled, but I am still running out of memory. It runs out after queuing, but when it starts receiving.


INFO: Configured URIs queue max in-memory size: 1,000
May 31, 2019 11:37:23 AM com.marklogic.developer.corb.Manager logOptions
INFO: Configured URIs queue temp dir: null
May 31, 2019 11:37:23 AM com.marklogic.developer.corb.Manager run
INFO: maximum heap size = 247 MiB
May 31, 2019 11:37:23 AM com.marklogic.developer.corb.Manager populateQueue
INFO: populating queue

Comment: How large are the URI values? Have you tried setting a smaller DISK-QUEUE-MAX-MEMORY-SIZE?

Comment: We are looking at 2 million  URIs. I tried binning, and this is with binning the 19 million total URIs.. this bin just seems to have more than the usual.

Comment: I will try the DISK-QUEUE-MAX-IN-MEMORY-SIZE.

Comment: The queuing is not the issue. I see the temp file being created. But after everything is queued, and it starts to process, how does that stuff get passed off? It seems like half of the 2.4 million URIs are passed off, leading to out of memory.

INFO: received 1,200,000/2,403,571: http://rdf.abbvienet.com/entity/sharepoint/document/75cb6d7e-6126-400d-8bab-1e6259265c6f

Answer (score 3):

The comment from @grtjn, above, solves the problem.

```
tasks.withType(JavaExec) { jvmArgs = ['-Xms1g', '-Xmx2g'] }
```